# If for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $\left\vert \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x) e^{-2 \pi ix \cdot t} dx \right\vert < \infty$, is $f(x) \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I know that if $f \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, 
$$ \left\vert\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x) e^{-2 \pi ix \cdot t} dx  \right\vert < \infty,~\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$$
However, I am not sure that if the **converse problem** holds true. That is
if 
$$\left\vert  \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x) e^{-2 \pi ix \cdot t} dx \right\vert < \infty,~\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$$
is $f \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$?

In another word, does there exist a function $f \not \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, 
$$\left\vert \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x) e^{-2 \pi ix \cdot t} dx \right\vert< \infty$$

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What about putting $t=0$?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: It might give an improperly Riemann-integrable function that is not Lebesgue-integrable.

Comment: @AlexM. My question is: what exactly does TeamBright mean by $\int g(x)\,dx<\infty$ when $g$ is a complex valued function?

Comment: TeamBright, it baffles me to see someone editing a post only to change "ture" into "true", and it baffles me even more to see another edit only to undo this correction...

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say a complex integral is $<\infty.$ Please edit.

Comment: What does the integral even mean if $f\notin L^1?$

Comment: I am sorry, I am trying to edit

Comment: @zhw., couldn't it mean an improper Riemann integral?

Comment: @AlexM. Certainly it could, but if so the OP should say so.

Comment: Was I wrong? Why could not it be a Lebesgue-integrable

Comment: On the converse, how do you define the integral if $f \notin L^1$ to begin with?

Comment: Even assuming that you are using some more general integral such that $\int_{\mathbb R} f(t) e^{-i2\pi xt}\ dx$ makes sense for a function which is not *a priori* known to be $L^1$, note that the Fourier transform of any $L^1$ function is continuous. So, finiteness of the defining integral for all $t \in \mathbb R$ is not sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other users pointed out, you may want to clarify which definition of integral you are working with.

If you are working with Lebesgue integral, then the question is almost a tautology because $f(x)e^{-2\pi i tx}$ is Lebesgue integrable exactly when $f(x)$ is. This is simply because $|f(x)e^{-2\pi i tx}| = |f(x)|$. So the minimal assumption for $f$ which is required to make sense of $\int_{\Bbb{R}} f(x)e^{-2\pi i t x} \, dx$ already answers your question.

That said, you have to work with other notion of integral in order to make your question meaningful.

For instance, you may abuse the notation so that your integral stands for the Fourier transform as isometry $\mathcal{F} : L^2(\Bbb{R}) \to L^2(\Bbb{R})$. Then the answer is negative as pointed out by @Bungo; the image of $L^1(\Bbb{R})\cap L^2(\Bbb{R})$ under $\mathcal{F}$ is strictly contained in $C_0(\Bbb{R})$, the set of continuous functions on $\Bbb{R}$ which vanishes near $\pm \infty$. Clearly there are tons of $L^2$-functions which do not lie in $C_0(\Bbb{R})$.

Or you may extend the Fourier transform on a subspace of $L_{\mathrm{loc}}^{1}(\Bbb{R})$ by adopting a suitable summability method, but even mild forms of such procedure produce counter-examples. For instance, consider the following extension using improper Lebesgue integral:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)e^{-2\pi i tx} \, dx := \lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-R}^{R} f(x)e^{-2\pi i tx} \, dx. $$

Then we have examples like

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(\pi x^2)e^{-2\pi i t x}\, dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \cos(\pi t^2) + \sin (\pi t^2) \right). $$

Answer (score 0):

No, take f such as: f(x) = 1 if  -1 < x < 1.

f(x) = 1 / abs(x) elsewhere

The Fourier transform exists and the integral of f over R doesn't.

Comment: The Fourier transform may exist in the $L^2$ sense, or in the sense of distributions, but not as defined by the integral $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) e^{-i\omega x}\ dx$.

Comment: It does because the integral of cos(at)/t from 1 to infinity exist for any given a. You just have to split into real and imaginary part.

Comment: Are you using an improper integral? If we consider only properly (Lebesgue) integrable functions, then $\int f(x) e^{-i \omega x}\ dx$ exists if and only if $\int |f(x)|\ dx$ exists.

Comment: Oh, I know that $\int f(x)e^{-2 \pi i x}dx$ exists if  $\int |f(x)|dx$. But I do not know why it is "if and only if"

Comment: No, you know that if a function is lebesgue-integrable then Fourier-Transform exists. Why do you think that my function has no Fourier transform? The integral exist for all t.

Comment: In what sense do you say that the integral exists for all $t$? It is not true if we are talking about the (proper) Lebesgue integral, which requires that the integrals of the positive and negative parts of the real and imaginary components (four different integrals of positive real-valued functions) must all be finite. Indeed, this is exactly equivalent to the requirement that the function must be absolutely integrable.

Comment: @Blaut Does the integral exist if $t=0?$

Comment: @TeamBright You still haven't told us in the converse what the integral even means!!!

Comment: I see, I will try to figure out how to edit this question. Thanks a lot

Comment: Alright the t=0 destroys everything.

Comment: @Blaut You could define $f(x) = 1/x, |x| \ge 1, f(x) = 0, |x|<1$ and then the Fourier integral will exist for all $t$-AS AN IMPROPER INTEGRAL. I don't know why people aren't mentioning this important last bit.

Comment: @zhw. Just a pedantic note: your example works for $t \neq 0$, but depending on what you mean by improper integral, it may not work for $t=0$. If we define the improper integral as $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} = {\displaystyle \lim_{a \to -\infty} \lim_{b \to \infty}} \int_a^b$, then it doesn't exist for $t=0$. But it does exist if we use symmetric limits: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} = {\displaystyle \lim_{c \to \infty}}\int_{-c}^{c}$. If I'm not mistaken, the former is the usual definition of the improper integral on $\mathbb R$, whereas the latter is the Cauchy principal value.

Comment: @Bungo True. I was thinking PV.